# Expected an Identifier error at #ifndef

Tags: c++

This is my implementation of priority queues using heaps but I am getting an error in this code below. The error says "Expected an identifier" at #ifndef "HEAP_H"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef "HEAP_H"
#define "HEAP_H"


class Heap {

public:
    Heap();

    Heap(int c);

    Heap(const int * Priorities, const int * Elements, int s, int c);

    Heap(const Heap & Heap1, const Heap & Heap2, int c);

    ~Heap();

    // Accessors
    bool empty() const { return hSize == 0; }; // True iff Heap is empty.
    int size() const { return hSize; }; // Current size of Heap.
    int capacity() const { return hCapacity; }; // Current capacity.
    int peekMin() const { return A[0].element; } // Peek at minimum priority element.
    int peekMinPriority() const { return A[0].priority; } // Peek at minimum priority.

                                                          // Modifiers
    void insert(int element, int priority); // Insert the pair <element,priority>.
    int extractMin(); // Remove and return the highest (minimum) priority element.

private:
    class Pair {
    public:
        int element;
        int priority;
    };

    Pair* A; // Array containing heap contents.
    int hCapacity; // Max number of elements (= size of A).
    int hSize; // Current number of elements.

               // Repairs ordering invariant after adding leaf at A[i].
    void trickleUp(int i);

    // Repairs ordering invariant for sub-tree rooted at index i,
    //   when A[i] may be have larger priority than one of its children,
    //   but the subtrees of its children are heaps.
    void trickleDown(int i);

    // Establishes ordering invariant for entire array contents.
    void heapify(); //(Same as "make_heap" in lectures.)

                    // Useful for implementing trickle up and down
    void swap(int i, int j);
};

#endif
```

My header file is named heap.h but I am getting an "Expected an identifier" error at #ifndef "HEAP_H" in this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never, ever add `using namespace` directives at global scope in header files. Ever. It may not cause horrible issues in your own small projects, but it's a very bad practice when collaborating with others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` to check if something has been defined. So it should be

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
```

Answer (score 3):

Macros are [*identifiers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) (unquoted symbols), and not strings:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
```

Note the lack of quotes.